# WebStorm - Remove option from right click menu

Tags: webstorm

Hello I'm using WebStorm and would like to know how I could remove the `Compile Typescript` options from here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Settings (Preferences on macOS)`
2. `Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars`
3. Locate the `Editor Popup Menu` menu and adjust it as needed

[image]